# JOLT Show If else

Tags: json, jolt

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it, I want to get data from "B" if it exists and if it doesn't exist then data from "A".

I've done it but it only works for B, could it be improved in my code?

Input with B:
`

```
{
  "P": {
    "A": {
      "One": {
        "Two": {
          "Three": [
            {
              "ID": "123456",
              "Some": {
                "ID_1": "123456789",
                "AAA": "aaa"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "B": {
      "One": {
        "Two": {
          "Three": [
            {
              "ID": "654321",
              "Some": {
                "ID_1": "987654321",
                "BBB": "bbb"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`

Input without B:

`

```
{
  "P": {
    "A": {
      "One": {
        "Two": {
          "Three": [
            {
              "ID": "123456",
              "Some": {
                "ID_1": "123456789",
                "AAA": "aaa"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`

JSON Spec:

`

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "P": {
        "B": {
          "One": {
            "Two": {
              "Three": {
                "*": {
                  "ID": "null"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "P": {
        "B": {
          "One": {
            "Two": {
              "Three": {
                "*": {
                  "ID": {
                    "null": {
                      "@(6,A.One.Two.Three.ID)": "Data.ID",
                      "@(6,A.One.Two.Three.Some.ID_1)": "Data.ID_1",
                      "@(6,A.One.Two.Three.Some.AAA)": "Data.AAA"
                    },
                    "*": {
                      "@(2,ID)": "Data.ID",
                      "@(2,Some.ID_1)": "Data.ID_1",
                      "@(2,Some.BBB)": "Data.BBB"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

`

Output:

{
"Data" : {
"ID" : "654321",
"ID_1" : "987654321",
"BBB" : "bbb"
}
}